# Why I am getting not found error on js/index.php/x.js in Magento?

Tags: .htaccess, magento, magento-1.9

Magento forgotpassword.phtml page uses
js/index.php/x.js?f=prototype/prototype.js,prototype/validation.js,mage/adminhtml/events.js,mage/adminhtml/form.js,scriptaculous/effects.js
and this returns custom Magento template 404 error page.
Apparently js/index.php script is supposed to concatenate provided scripts (for optimization purpose) and return virtual x.js file which physically does not exist on the server.
But in my case this does not work. For testing purpose at the beginning of js/index.php I added logging some info to a file. When I invoke js/index.php an entry is added to the script. When I invoke js/index.php/x.js nothing is logged meaning that control is never passed to js/index.php.
Browsing internet I found information that using nginx for static files can introduce the problem, but I turned nginx off in my hosting settings. Admin of my hosting claims that this works in case of everybody's else Magento installations on that server whether nginx is turned on or off.
How can I troubleshoot the problem? What should I look for? Can something in the .htacces be blamed for it? Would the fact that my Magento installation is located in subfolder contribute to this problem somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the root cause of the problem. Since I have a multi Website Magento setup I need to add extra entries to my Magento .htaccess setting environment variables based on which right website is selected to be shown in the frontend. I used a template proposed on several internet articles. It goes like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1$
RewriteRule (.*) $1 [E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:domain1]
RewriteRule (.*) $1 [E=MAGE_RUN_TYPE:website]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain2$
RewriteRule (.*) $1 [E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:domain2]
RewriteRule (.*) $1 [E=MAGE_RUN_TYPE:website]
```

The issue went away when I used another solution (which however may be not supporter by some servers):

```
SetEnvIf Host ^domain1$ MAGE_RUN_CODE=domain1
SetEnvIf Host ^domain1$ MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
SetEnvIf Host ^domain2$ MAGE_RUN_CODE=domain1
SetEnvIf Host ^domain2$ MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
```